# float:left problem

Tags: html, css

i have 3 div in my page. named with blok1, blok2 and blok3.

i'm adding to {float:left;} for blok1 div but getting this result:

[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7lCQ.jpg)

i want to get this result.

[screenshot link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB33Z.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to show some code, I assume that you're adding a background to the div, rather than adding content to the div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrap div {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #div3 { clear: left; }
</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
    <div id="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the float attribute to blok1 and blok2 in order to get one next to the other.

note: each div have to have a defined width and height.

Answer (score 0):

so http://jsfiddle.net/6v5gM/

instead of http://jsfiddle.net/JmWZp/1/

just use a display:table; on the divs

Answer (score 0):

you should probably have it like this

```
#blok1 {float:left;}
#blok2 {float:right;}
#blok3 {clear:both;}
```

or ideally

If you want it like in a column, you should use it like this.

```
#ltCol {float:left;}
#rtCol {float:right;}

<div id="ltCol">
    <div id="blok1"></div>
    <div id="blok1"></div>
</div>
<div id="rtCol">
     <div id="blok2"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```